# Getting KMeans silhouette average score without using the Kmeans import

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a KMeans function I made takes the input `def kmeans(x,k, no_of_iterations):` and returns the following `return points, centroids` it gets plotted perfectly, the code for that isn't very relevant. But I want to calculate for it, **the silhouette score and graph this for each value**.

```
#Load Data
data = load_digits().data
pca = PCA(2)

#Transform the data
df = pca.fit_transform(data)
X= df
#y = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
#Applying our function
label, centroids = kmeans(df,10,1000)#returns points value and centroids
y = label.fit_predict(data)
 
#Visualize the results

u_labels = np.unique(label)
for i in u_labels:
    plt.scatter(df[label == i , 0] , df[label == i , 1] , label = i)
    plt.scatter(centroids[:,0] , centroids[:,1] , s = 80, color = 'k')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**the above is code for running the KMeans plot**
Below is my attempt to calculate silhouette. This is from an example that imports from KMeans but I don't really want to do that nor did it work with my code.

```
silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(X, y)
print("The average silhouette_score is :", silhouette_avg)

# Compute the silhouette scores for each sample
sample_silhouette_values = silhouette_samples(X, y)
```

You may notice that there is no value here for y, as I have found y is supposed to be the amount of clusters I think? So I had it as 10 at first and it give an error message. I don't know if from this code anyone could tell me what I do next to get this value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

from yellowbrick.cluster import KElbowVisualizer, SilhouetteVisualizer

mpl.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (9,6)

# Generate synthetic dataset with 8 blobs
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=12, centers=8, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

# Instantiate the clustering model and visualizer
model = KMeans()
visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(model, k=(4,12))

visualizer.fit(X)    # Fit the data to the visualizer
visualizer.poof()    

# Instantiate the clustering model and visualizer 
model = KMeans(8)
visualizer = SilhouetteVisualizer(model)

visualizer.fit(X)    # Fit the data to the visualizer
visualizer.poof()    # Draw/show/poof the data
```

Also, see this.

https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/cluster/silhouette.html